# Split array in chunks with a slight modification

Tags: javascript, arrays

The question is simple. I've got an array, something like

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    maxChunkLength = 3;
```

I need to split it to a number of arrays, to get this:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9], [9, 10]]
```

Notice that the last element of a chunk should be the first element of the chunk next to it.

Does anybody know the best way to do it?

Comment: ...And what have you tried so far? You would need to figure out how many times you need to create an array - so `numChunks = array.length/maxChunkLength` and the `while(x < numChunks)` loop through the first block of numbers etc.

Comment: "best way" is likely a matter of opinion...  what do you mean by "best" ?

Comment: The most beautiful one.

Comment: What part of this are you stuck on?  What do you need help with?

Comment: I know how to just split it to chunks, I am struggling to find the way to keep the last element of chunk to be the same as the first element of the next chunk.

Comment: @Adjit As you can see in the example of what I need, the number of chunks is `5`, but `array.length / maxChunkLength` is 3.33

Comment: How are you splitting it into chunks?  Can you show us that code?  Maybe we can adapt it for this purpose.

Comment: @RocketHazmat. Sure. It's pretty easy to do with underscorejs: `chunks = _.toArray(_.groupBy(array, (el, i) => Math.floor(i / maxChunkLength)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this function might work for you,

```
function splitArray(array, chunk){      
    var i,j, rslt = [];
    chunk = chunk - 1;
    for (i=0,j=array.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
        rslt.push(array.slice(i,i+chunk +1));
    }
    return rslt;
}
```

examples

```
splitArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 3); //[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9], [9, 10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is around twice as fast as the accepted answer.

```js
function chunk(arr, chunkSize) {
    var curr = [], result = [], i, j;

    for (i=0, j=arr.length; i<j; i++) {
        curr.push(arr[i]);        
        if (curr.length === chunkSize) {
            result.push(curr);
            curr = [arr[i]];
        }
    }    

    if (curr.length !== chunkSize) {     
        result.push(curr);
    }
    
    return result;
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 3)));
```

Comment: this is actually faster because of the added steps involved with calling `.slice()`

Comment: seems like the OP is looking for "beauty" and not speed.  Mirror Mirror on the Wall...

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
var originalArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

var maxChunkLength = 3

var newArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < originalArray.length; maxChunkLength += 2) {

    var tempArray = [];

    for (var j = i; j < i+maxChunkLength; j++) {

        if (typeof originalArray[j] !== "undefined") {

            tempArray.push(originalArray[j]);
        } 
    }

newArray.push(tempArray);

tempArray = [];  
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind, the `maxChunkLength` is subject to change so you would need to make the increment `i += maxChunkLength-1`

Comment: Also, in this example, the last array only has 2 elements, `[9, 10]`.  You might want to add a check for that.

Comment: This will work only for arrays with length multiple of 3

Comment: It is also reasonable to assume that you may also have 1 element in the last array. Maybe consider using a temp array to loop through and push the elements and then add the temp array at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var el1 = 0, el2 = 0, el3 = 0;
var result = [];
var splitLength = 3;
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += (splitLength -1) ) {
    var tempArr = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < splitLength && arr[i+j]; j++) {
        tempArr.push(arr[i+j]);
    }

    result.push(tempArr);
}

console.log("[" + result.join("]\n[") + "]");
```